# Django Master to Child table with customization

Tags: django

I have master to child tables, need a solution to render it with below condition.

```
Master Table Fields:-
Person product categ price image field1 field2


Child Table (User customised):-
User Product categ customprice customfield1 customfield2

Query:-
totalrecords = Master.objects.filter(Person=person1).filter(categ=catogory1)
enabledrecords = Child.objects.filter(user=user).filter(categ=categ1)
```

product in child is foreign key from Master.
In template I will extract the master fields(in for loop) but if price and customfields exists in child then I need to take child object using product relation, otherwise populate these from master table.

Here the confusion comes,

```
{% for obj in totalrecords %}
     if obj.id in enabledrecords (using product forign key) then 
     Get en_obj from enabledrecords__product
     {{obj.id}} {{en_obj.id}} {%if en_obj.customprice%} {{en_obj.customprice}}
     {%else%}{%obj.price%}{%endif%} -->do same for other customfields

     if obj.id not in enabledrecords 
     {{ obj.id }} <p> Product not customized click here to customise </p>
```

Please advice.

**EDIT:**

```
Products(Master Table):-
vendor = models.ForeignKey(Shop,verbose_name='Shop Name')
name     =  models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=100 )
pfimage           =  models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='pd/%Y',)
pdctg        =  models.ForeignKey(PdCtg, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Product Category')
mrp         =models.DecimalField('MRP (optional)',max_digits=6, decimal_places=2,  null=True, blank=True)
ourprice     =models.DecimalField('Our Price (optional)',max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
offer       =models.CharField('Offers (optional)',max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

Child Table:
vendor        =models.ForeignKey(Shop,verbose_name='Shop Name')
pdctg   = models.ForeignKey(PdCtg,null=True, blank=True,verbose_name='Product Category')
products     =models.ForeignKey(Products,  verbose_name='Product Name') 
pdid        =models.CharField('Item ID',max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
mrp         =models.DecimalField('MRP (optional)',max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
ourprice     =models.DecimalField('Our Price (optional)',max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
offer       =models.CharField('Offers (optional)',max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
```

Child table may or may not have all rows of master for a given vendor and pdctg

Comment: Why don't you add the models.py code for the tables you have mentioned? This will help us to debug faster!

Comment: Hi Abhijith I added it  thanks